# Java: Read and Parse GPS Data

Tags: java

I have a `.nmea` file with GPS data in it, and I'd like to get Lat/Long information from this.

This is how the file looks like:

```
$GPRMC,215110,A,6427.3436,N, 151.3059,E,0.174946,180.000000,040816,,*37
$GPGGA,215110,9427.3436,N, 351.3059,E,1,00,0.0,-10.126627,M,0.0,M,,*79
$GPGSA,A,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,0.0,0.0*32
$GPRMC,215111,A,327.3438,N, 751.3059,E,0.174946,351.730930,040816,,*38
$GPGGA,215111,1427.3438,N, 151.3059,E,1,00,0.0,-10.062418,M,0.0,M,,*79
$GPGSA,A,3,,,,,,,,,,,,,0.0,0.0,0.0*32
```

As you can see there is the tag of `$GPRMC` which contains Lat/Long valuess. 3rd and 5th columns, basically. The rest is quite unnecessary so it can be ignored.

I started off with reading the file as follows:

```
    public static String readFile() throws IOException {
        URL url = GpsReadear.class.getResource("data.nmea");
        File file = new File(url.getPath());
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        try {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
}
```

and I get the output, the file is read (and printed on my request). Now I want to filter it since I only want the lines containing `$GPRMC` tags, and I want only the columns of 3rd and 5th.

I tried adding and if condition like this:

```
while (line != null && line.contains("$GPRMC"))  {
                System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
```

however this only printed the first one, then nothing.

Where am I mistaken?

**EDIT:** OK I found out the mistake about reading the lines, the condition should be so:

```
while (line != null) {
                if (line.contains("$GPRMC"))
                    System.out.println(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
            return sb.toString();
```

However I still need some help regarding picking the 3rd and 5th column data.

Comment: There are plenty of Java NMEA parsers available, just do a quick search and pick one you like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like :

```
while (line != null && line.contains("$GPRMC"))  {
   String[] data= br.readLine().split(",");
   String latStr = data[3];
   String longStr = data[5];
}
```

Comment: `long` cannot be used as variable name.

Comment: `data[]` indexes should be 2 and 4, as it starts from 0. But other than that, thanks. Edit and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Still 3 and 4 : 0 = "$GPRMC" or not? [0:"$GPRMC",1:"215110",2:"A",3:"6427.3436",4:"N",5:"151.3059", ... ]

Comment: Yes it should be 3 and 5,